# pygame window always gray

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to fill a window with a red color but all I get is a gray screen. Whatever I do (adding pictures etc) It only shows me a gray screen. Sound works but I can't get the images etc. Couldn't figure out it works on someone else's computer.

```
import pygame 

#initilize pygame 
pygame.init()

#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))


#title and icon
pygame.display.set_caption("uzay gemisi")
icon = pygame.image.load("ufo.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)


#game loop
running  = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #rgb red green blue
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: can you try running `python -c "import pygame"` in terminal? to see if its indeed installed

Comment: yeah it works.. says pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Comment: So can you add the full error message to you question

Comment: Actually, It doesn't give me any errors I should've point that out. when I try it on the Sublime text it doesn't say that import thing but the program doesn't work like It's supposed to be. It should give me a red screen. But it's only a gray screen and it also does not show me the icon of the app.

Comment: I tried your code, and the only lines i commented out was the ones involving the icon; the code works fine

Comment: @dashausdeshades Are you running it as administrator?

Comment: I encountered the same presumed bug and found a work-around that works for me on MacOS Mojave (10.14) on a Macbook Air from 2014:
After the update(), simply add "pygame.event.get()"
Don't ask me why, but for me it triggers the update; without it: light grey screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine on my end (when removing the 2 icon lines). However, to be able to close the window you want to add a pygame.quit() at the line after running = False in your events handler.